# Sound not working in kubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: kubuntu

There is no sound playing in kubuntu 14.04.But when I logging in with ubuntu 14.04 lts it works .Please help me to get sound in kubuntu

Comment: Does anything show in Multimedia/Sound settings? Also what hardware are you using, how did you install Kubuntu, and version of KDE is being used?

Comment: What sound card(s) ?